# Wordpress permalink sub category 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have the following custom permalink structure:
`/%category%/%postname%/` my category base is `.` the generated URLs looks like this:

```
/
/categoryA
/categoryA/categoryA1
/categoryA/categoryA1/postname
```

But I get an 404 Error for this URL `/categoryA/categoryA1`
When I change my custom permalink structure to this:
`/%category%/%category%/%postname%/` my category base is `.` the generated URLs looks like this:

```
/
/categoryA
/categoryA/categoryA1
/categoryA/categoryA1/categoryA/categoryA1/postname
```

Except for the "ugly" postname URL everything works.

In the third scenario:
my custom permalink structure is this: `/%category%/%postname%/` my category base is `empty` so wordpress put there the default one `category` the generated URLs looks like this:

```
/
/category/categoryA
/category/categoryA/categoryA1
/categoryA/categoryA1/postname
```

Except for the "ugly" category URL's everything works.

I also tried the third option with an filter:

```
add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'remove_category', 100, 2);
function remove_category( $string, $type )
{
        if ( $type != 'single' && $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) )
        {
            $url_without_category = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );
            return trailingslashit( $url_without_category );
        }
    return $string;
}
```

Then the URL's look like this:

```
/
/categoryA
/categoryA/categoryA1
/categoryA/categoryA1/postname
```

But then I get also an 404 Error for this URL: `/categoryA/categoryA1`

How can I get nice looking URL's without errors?

Comment: Hi Oliver, have you found a solution to this? I ran into the the same problem and i'm really surprised that it exists and is not fixed. the permalink structure you strive for: category/subcategory/postname should not only be working, it should be the default permalink setting of any website.